# Recommender system that connect users with each other , should I go for content based or collaborative filtering?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, statistics, recommender-system, similarity

I am trying to build a system where user come on the platform and he chooses a topic(predefined few topics) and then we connect him with any random online user who chooses the same topic. Then they can do conversation.

Now, I am trying to connect them smartly based on user's historical data (users with whom he had match earlier along with time duration of their conversation, and raing after the conversation etc). and his basic profile data.

How can I use collaborative filtering here, because I don't have any product here and their are very few users available online(10-15) at any time so I have to connect any one of them.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I disagree with your premise that you don't have a product - the conversation is your product. Do you collect your conversation data? If so, you can apply NLP techniques to it, treat it as a product and then make recommendations based on the content of the conversations. That should be important to you because a long, enjoyable conversation 
 - and the topics within - may have *nothing* to do with the original topic the person(s) chose.

Comment: No, I am not storing their conversation. But in collaborative filtering we create matrix between user and item. Can we create matrix between user and user. and after call we have rating provided to user. so we can say here user is also a product. what you say ?

Comment: Yes, you *may* be able to do that but you're going to need a long list of factors for each user in order to make that work. But then what? You're going to run into an issue where User A matches with User B because of conversation topic but User C is a better match because of the recommender, but no match via topic, right? Or will you be eliminating the match via topic?

Comment: What if first, we will filter the available users with the topic and then see best rating user with the help of recommender. I think it will work?

Comment: Only you can answer that. It depends on the depth/quality of the data you have and the power of the resulting algorithm(s)

Comment: Piyush, I would agree with you that you don't have a product, or rather the product is the user ( ie you are creating user user similarlity). I would read up on factorisation machines...I think they provide you a clear statistical model to build on. There it is clear you are just creating interaction coefficients from sparse data.... So the model could be predict conversation length based on topic, user a data, user b data and axb interactions

Answer (score 0):

You can use collaborative filtering with implicit features. However, I would first start with an even simpler approach. Maybe you could start using a distance metric, such as cosine similarity, or search for nearest neighbours using KNN.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am also trying to do something similar suggested by you. I am calculating the centroid(using avg of all the feature vector) of all the previous good conversation of that user and finding cosine similarity between centroid and online users feature vector. And the closest user we can say will have good conversation. But I am struggling here to improve accuracy(precision at 1). How can I improve accuracy ?